# How to put alert on my all anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

How to put alert on my all anchor tag using javascript and alert box also show the link &  text of anchor tag

Comment: I need more context to give you a useful answer.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/VBgak/

Answer (score 2):

You can [**document.getElementsByTagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), it returns a HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

[**EventTarget.addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");    
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length ; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(this.href);
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        }, false);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tf3F3/1/)

Note: I have use [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), to cancel anchors default behaviour and `addEventListener` is supported in IE9+

Answer (score 0):

witch jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    alert('text:' + $(this).text() + ', href: ' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Although this is not how Stackoverflow works. You should show what you have tried so far, not ask people to do it for you

Comment: I believe `alert` takes just one argument

Comment: True. Too used to use console.log, thanks.